# Appengine pipeline, how to let function execute right after the pipeline work finish

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pipeline

https://code.google.com/p/appengine-pipeline/wiki/GettingStarted#Execution_ordering

I tried to add a callback function which execute after the Log2Bq done. 
But it doesn't work either I use `pipeline.After` or `pipeline.InOrder`. In the following code sample, the taskqueue will execute immediate without waiting for Log2Bq. To fix the issue, 
do I need to create another pipeline to hold the taskqueue in order to make the execute order works?

```
class Log2Stat(base_handler.PipelineBase):
    def run(self, _date):
        print "start track"
        with pipeline.InOrder():
            yield pipelines.Log2Bq()

            print "finish track"
            taskqueue.add(
                url='/worker/update_daily_stat',
                params={
                    "date": str(_date.date())
                }
            )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pipeline.InOrder()` and `pipeline.After()` are only for ordering pipelines execution, not code execution.

There is a method called *finalized*, that is executed right after the last output is written, that is when your `Log2Bq()` pipeline finish it's execution, so:

```
class Log2Stat(base_handler.PipelineBase):
    def run(self, _date):
        print "start track"
        yield pipelines.Log2Bq()

    def finalized(self):
        print "finish track"
        taskqueue.add(
            url='/worker/update_daily_stat',
            params={
                "date": str(_date.date())
            }
         )
```

If you want to use pipeline.InOrder() or pipeline.After() you should wrap your taskqueue code in other pipeline and yield it after `pipelines.Log2Bq()`

```
with pipeline.InOrder():
      yield pipelines.Log2Bq()
      yield pipelines.YourOtherPipeline()
```

Comment: Thx. I finally got it!!